# Microsoft Stream - Event when video is finished

Tags: javascript, events, stream

- I want to embed a ***Microsoft stream video*** in an `HTML` page, and
  trigger an action when the video is finished ( display an image,
  redirect to page, open a confirm box).
- In the documentation page
  https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/stream/portal-embed-video, I can
  generate an `iframe` to display the video.
- But I can't find the equivalent of ***Youtube***'s `onStateChange` event
  https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Events

  Is there a way to do that with ***Microsoft stream video***?

Thanks